# Custom fields are not displaying in page with multiple loops

Tags: custom-field, customization

I have multiple loops on my home page. I am trying to display custom fields in each loop. But some of them are not showing. Any idea, why? Here is the code:

```
//check for Featured Events here
   $featured = new WP_Query (array(
   'category_name' => 'Featured Events',
   'posts_per_page' => 2) 
   ); 
    if ($featured -> have_posts()) { 
    while ($featured->  have_posts()) : $featured -> the_post(); ?>

<h2 class="featured"> <?php the_title(); ?> </h2>  
      <h3 class="featured">
    <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Date', true); ?>  </h3>

<h4 class="featured">
    <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Start Time', true); ?>
      <?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'End Time', true) != "") { ; ?>
     &nbsp;-&nbsp; 
    <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'End Time', true); }?> </h4>

<!--only print sponsor if value there  -->
 <?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Sponsor', true) != "") { ; ?>

<h5 class="featured">

<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Sponsor', true); ?></h5>
<?php }; ?>
 <?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Cost', true) != "") { ; ?>

 <p class="cost"> 

<?php echo 'Cost: '. get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Cost', true); ?> </p> <?php }; 
    if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Location', true) != "") { ; ?>

 <h6 class="featured">

<?php echo 'Location: '. get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Location', true); ?>
    </h6>

 <?php }; 
    global $more;
$more = 0; 
  the_content('Read more please'); 
  if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'link', true) != "") { ; ?>

 <p> <a href="
 <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'link', true); ?> " 

> Click here for more information </a> </p>

 <?php } endwhile; 
     } 
     wp_reset_query(); ?> 

           </div> <!-- content_inner -->
         </div> <!-- content -->
       </div>   <!-- end 2 column wrap div   -->

           <div  id="lftcol">
      <div id="lcol_inner">

<?php 
   $ann_query = new WP_Query (array(
   'category_name' => 'announcement',
   'orderby'=> 'modified',
   'posts_per_page' => 5) );

    if ($ann_query -> have_posts()) { 
    while ($ann_query->  have_posts()) : $ann_query -> the_post();

    if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue; //This is the Magic Line
// echo 'NON urgent announcement should follow '; ?>

 <h2 class="featured"> <?php the_title(); ?> </h2>

    <?php 
//The code must be inserted ahead of the call the_content, but AFTER the_post()
global $more;
$more = 0; ?>

<h3 class="featured">

<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Date', true); ?>  

</h3>

 <h4 class="featured"> 

    <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Start Time', true); ?>
     <?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'End Time', true) != "") { ; ?>
     &nbsp;-&nbsp; 
    <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'End Time', true); }?> 

</h4>

     <?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Location', true) != "") { ; ?>

     <h6 class="featured">

<?php echo 'Location: '. get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Location', true); ?>

</h6> 

<?php }; 
    the_content('Read more please');
    if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'link', true) != "") { ; ?>

<p> <a href="

<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'link', true); ?> 

" > Click here for more information </a> </p>

    <?php } 
            endwhile;   }
            wp_reset_query(); ?>

        </div>
           </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are problems in your code. I'd like to recommend you to code on WordPress by opening relevant Codex pages for reference that, you are not mistaking.

First of all, in `WP_Query()` you used `'category_name' => 'Featured Events'`. But according to codex, you can't use Category name here, you have to use **Category Slug**, and a Category slug cannot contain a space within, they have to be connected with an underscore. ([Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters))

At second, in `get_post_meta()` your key is not right. Because a key cannot contain spaces within. You have to connect separate strings with underscore, like `start_time`(**not** Start Time). I guess the keys are working where you coded with a single string like `Date`. ([Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta#Examples))

And lastly, at the end of each query, you used `wp_reset_query();` to reset the query. But according to Codex, for WP_Query() the reset query code is **not** `wp_reset_query();`, but `wp_reset_postdata()`. ([Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata))

That's all.

#### ADDITIONAL

In one of my project I used many custom fields. So I made two reusable functions for using in all-over my project. Just paste the following in your `funcitons.php` within `<?php` and `?>`.

```
/**
 * REUSABLE POST_META FUNCTION
 */

function has_custom_field( $fieldName = '' ) {
    global $post;
    $fetchedCustomField = get_post_meta($post->ID, $fieldName, true);
    $CFchecker = ($fetchedCustomField == '') ? '0' : '1';
    return (bool) $CFchecker;
}

function custom_field( $fieldName = '' ) {
    global $post;
    $fetchedCustomField = get_post_meta($post->ID, $fieldName, true);
    return $fetchedCustomField;
}
```

And use them like:

```
<?php if(has_custom_field('date')) { echo custom_field('date'); } else { echo 'no date'; } ?>
```

And one additional tips: whenever you are coding on WordPress always use the `WP_DEBUG` to **`'true'`** in `wp-config.php`. And don't forget to set it to `'false'` again after the completion of the development. ([Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress))

Good luck!

## EDIT

To specify Custom Field, just under post/page Add the custom field like this:
[image: custom field str_date]

If you custom field is defined like the image, then the `get_post_meta()` would be:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'start_date', true); ?>
```

But for using custom field, I love to use [Advanced Custom Fields plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields).

Comment: @user45758: if the answer is good, we upvote the answer, and if the answer solved the problem, we click on the tick-mark to mark the answer as accepted. It's not mandatory, but recommended. :)

Comment: I would be happy to upvote the answer. I am still reviewing it. One thing I don't understand is how do I know the correct way to specify the key on the get_post_meta call. Is it just by default that it is represented as 'start_time'?

Comment: @user45758 See my edit